# Calling a Stored procedure with SimpleJdbcCall returns null result set from Temp table. The stored procedure have no input and out put paramets

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures

I have to call stored procedures From java spring. The procedures doesn't have input and out put parameters. when I call stored procedure using SimpleJdbcCall, it returns null result. How can I fix this Problem? Thank you

### Stored Procedure

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."Records" () 
 RESULT ( Number    integer 
 , Alias     varchar(255) 
 , File      varchar(255) 
 , ConnCount integer 
 , PageSize  integer 
 , LogName   varchar(255) 
 ) 
 BEGIN 
 DECLARE dbid integer; 
 DECLARE local temporary table t_db_info 
 ( Number    integer      null 
 , Alias     varchar(255) null 
 , File      varchar(255) null 
 , ConnCount integer      null 
 , PageSize  integer      null 
 , LogName   varchar(255) null 
 ) on commit delete rows; 
 set dbid=next_database(null); 
 lbl: loop 
 if dbid is null then 
 leave lbl 
 end if 
 ; 
 insert into t_db_info values( 
 dbid,db_property('Alias', 
 dbid),db_property('File', 
 dbid),db_property('ConnCount', 
 dbid),db_property('PageSize', 
 dbid),db_property('LogName', 
 dbid)); 
 set dbid=next_database(dbid) 
 end loop lbl 
 ; 
 select * from t_db_info 
 ORDER BY alias 
 END
```

Java Code

---

```
public class Generic <T>{

protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
protected SimpleJdbcCall procReadAllorgs;

public GenericDAO(DataSource ds) {
    this.procReadAllorgs = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withProcedureName("DBA.Records")
                .returningResultSet("records",
                BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Records.class));                       
        init();
    }
}


DAO Impl class



    public class  OrganDAOImpl implements Generic <T> {

public List getList() {
        Map m = procReadAllorgs.execute(new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
        return (List) m.get("records");
    }
   }
```

Controller class

```
@RequestMapping("/org")
public class TestController {
      @Autowired
      protected  OrganDAOImpl organDAOImpl;
@RequestMapping(value = "/sunday", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
         public @ResponseBody List getAll() {
             logger.debug("calling the controller...");
             return  OrganDAOImpl.getList();

} 
 }
```

Model class

```
public class Records {
    private Integer Number;
    private String Alias;
    private String File;
    private Integer ConnCount;
    private Integer PageSize;
    private String LogName;
       //getter and setter 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this procedure returning anything?!
It doesn't have an out parameter to return it, (I am not a plsql expert)

```
.withProcedureName("Records")
.withCatalogName("DBA")
.withSchemaName(schema);
```

two cases you will get a null from the DB.

1- if the call is wrong and you don't have exception handling/ try and catch
2- the procedure does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: How to get an output param back from simplejdbccall!! I'm using MSSQL Server with Java Spring Framework.

I checked my stored procedure and discovered I forgot to mark the @out_personId variable as output:

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNewUser]( @in_firstName nvarchar(20), @in_lastName nvarchar(20),@in_addressLine1 nvarchar(50), @in_addressLine2 nvarchar(50), @in_addressLine3 nvarchar(50), @in_addressLine4 nvarchar(50),@in_dob datetime, @in_gender nvarchar(1), @in_email nvarchar(100), @in_mobileNo nvarchar(50), @in_landLineNo nvarchar(50),@out_personId int`**`output`**`)`

After this change (in bold) I was able to read the returned int value via SimpleJDBCCall. Here is the code sample:

```
public Person createPerson(final Person person) {

        SimpleJdbcCall storedProcedure = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                .withProcedureName("spNewUser")
                .withReturnValue();

        SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                                    .addValue("in_firstName", person.getFirstName())
                                    .addValue("in_lastName", person.getLastName())
                                    .addValue("in_addressLine1", person.getAddressLine1())
                                    .addValue("in_addressLine2", person.getAddressLine2())
                                    .addValue("in_addressLine3", person.getAddressLine3())
                                    .addValue("in_addressLine4", person.getAddressLine4())
                                    .addValue("in_dob", new java.sql.Date(person.getDob().getTime()))
                                    .addValue("in_gender", person.getGender())
                                    .addValue("in_email", person.getEmail())
                                    .addValue("in_mobileNo", person.getMobileNo())
                                    .addValue("in_landLineNo", person.getLandLineNo())
                                    .addValue("out_personId", 0);

        Map<String, Object> output = storedProcedure.execute(params);
        Integer id = (Integer) output.get("out_personId");
        person.setId(id);
        return person;
}
```

Comment: i tried u above sample but getting error" [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.13] [Error 5531] [SQLState HY000] Named-list is not supported for arguments of a procedure." any thoughts?